# Convert m4f files into single mp4 video

Tags: video, mp4, segment

I have downloaded a video on the android app, but it can play only in the app. The app data folder in file manager contains following files:

1. master.mpd file;
2. One folder contains audio files - naming init.mp4 and various segment0.m4f, segment1.m4f, segment2.muf...... and so on;
3. the Second folder contains video files - naming init.mp4 and various segment0.m4f, segment1.m4f, segment2.muf...... and so on;

File link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjBBpK2IR8lagvF6t89kJWMeC3XDOA?e=TIft0a

I tried to merge Pt. 2 & Pt. 3 files with InviDowloader and it start playing in VLC but the quality of video is heavily distorted, only very few things are visible.
I think it is because the content is protected/encrypted.

I think that the master.mpd file may help but don't know how. I am not a technical person. Please guide.

Comment: have you found any solution. I am also facing similar problem

Comment: The link is dead, have you considered using `ffmpeg` or [GPAC](https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/downloads/)'s `mp4box` command?